# ErrorsOverflow?

Tags: discussion

I think there is a need for a Stack Overflow where the topics are exclusively about **errors**. So often I copy & paste my error/exception into Google and end up on Stack Overflow. But wouldn't it be great if there was a *definitive* place to go for "how to fix X error"? Then compilers, interpreters, editors, shells, and bug trackers could take advantage of the repeatable nature of error codes to provide a link directly to the discussion page(s) for that error.

Is this an idea that you would support in Area 51? Or do you think this idea would be better served by a wiki? Because I can host a wiki myself, but the idea only works if it gains traction and is used by others. If it were a Stack Exchange site, that might encourage adoption and scale better.

Comment: Do you believe that this isn't something you can already ask on SO?

Comment: It's qualitatively different. I wouldn't want Stack Overflow to suddenly get overwhelmed with questions that aren't "questions". The question title would just be the error message, as an open-ended question to index the discussion thread. For example: "Error: spawn ENOENT". It's not a question per se. However, currently if you search SO for "Error: spawn ENOENT" there are 582 questions. But they have that in common.

I know Stack Overflow can be very picky about what types of questions it allows, and open ended ones are not usually accepted.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. You're right, lists of things don't work here. But they don't really work on the _platform_, I.e., the QA format. Having another SE site isn't likely to change that.

Comment: > they don't really work on the platform, I.e., the QA format.

That's my concern. What platform would work well for large lists of things with discussions?

Comment: Do you think anyone is aiming to become an expert in errors? If not, how are you going to get people to frequent the site enough to get things answered?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is an actual need that is not currently being served by Stack Overflow. Questions *asking* for lists are indeed off topic here but suggestions to solve a specific error message typically come with a list of different answers trying to fix the problem - or even answers with a list of things to try.

Comment: @RobertLongson Everyone becomes an expert at the error they are trying to solve right that hour. I think lots of people would search for their error, find no answer or find the current answers out of date or unsatisfactory, solve their problem, then post their solution. It wouldn't be a forum of experts as much as people blazing trails in a forest of errors for other people to follow.

Answer (score 18):

Here's the deal:  errors are the direct result of malformed code (or bugs in a third party platform, which is still malformed code).  The code that one is running which produces these errors *can* be brought to Stack Overflow very plainly and simply; we just ask that the questions follow a typical pattern:

- A clear description of the problem
- What you did to try to solve it (code here, usually)
- What you expected
- What you got (including error message)
- What you tested it with (test data, inputs, etc)

There's no reason to have a separate site to cordon that stuff off.  Provided the question follows the rough heuristic, it's fine here.

Comment: For difficult errors, that is reasonable to ask. However "what you did to try to solve it (code here, usually)" is usually, "1) I googled the error message, 2) I read through the first page of search results, which were all links to Stack Overflow, 3) I tried to figure out which if any of these SO posters had the same problem I had, 4) I tried the suggestions on those pages".

Comment: You end up with lots of duplicates. (Citation: see the number of questions marked as duplicate on Stack Overflow.) The main reason for those duplicates is that steps 1-3 of that process are _not_ as effective as they could be. We could more accurately help users solve their real-life coding problems by going straight from the error message to the list of suggestions to try and accompanying discussion.

Comment: @WilliamHilton: I don't see how this solves any "duplicate" problem at all.  Yes, there are a lot of questions with this error message, and yes it involves a bit of sleuthing to figure out which specific question helps your specific situation, but **that doesn't change at all** even with a dedicated site for errors.  **Everyone's code is unique.**  The error message may occur with someone doing something similar, and the onus truly is on the OP to figure out where the lines intersect.  If they're not willing or not capable of doing that, then there's nothing else we can do to help them.

Comment: Well by that reasoning Stack Overflow is unnecessary and doesn't solve any problem because you can find the answers by sleuthing around on old PHP forums and Github issues. If you're not interested in helping that's fine, but *no one's code is unique* and the chance that the error you encounter has never happened before is so miniscule, it's hubris to think your error is a special snowflake. The tuple of (os, application, error message) will probably only have a few unique solutions, and if it's a recently released software, hundreds of other people will be having the same error this month.

Comment: To clarify, a lot of the kinds of errors I'm taking about happen *trying to use other people's software* not errors in software you yourself are writing.

Comment: @WilliamHilton:  If you're just talking about using someone else's application which isn't directly related to programming, then you're not on-topic here for Stack Overflow.  If it was on topic for Stack Overflow, then some kind of stack trace or error message would be readily available and easy to insert into a new question, provided that it was well-formed and well-researched; that is, you're not just looking for someone to Google the stack trace for you.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I'm talking about the errors you encounter when trying to compile libraries, use frameworks, use APIs, configure plugins. You get a error message. And yes, you could easily put that error message into a new question. BUT first StackOverflow expects you to Google it, and research it... but that is a catch 22 because that research usually just takes you to StackOverflow. But now you are just searching StackOverflow.

Comment: @WilliamHilton:  I fail to see how this is an issue.  Why wouldn't you want to search Stack Overflow for the solution since *so many* developers already rely on it?  At a bare minimum, I'm looking for someone to at least have done *some* searching around before they formulate their question here.  For context, I refer you [to this question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1079354)

Comment: Wow. That question you refer to is actually an **excellent** example of why asking a question on StackOverflow is literally a measure of last resort. Unless you've completely exhausted all alternatives, there is a high probability you'll be torn to shreds (and voted a duplicate). I use StackOverflow almost every day, but I only ask about 1 question a year. But ironically, while asking a question on SO is a *last* resort, searching through SO is the usually the *first* resort.

Comment: SO is poorly organized to assist programmers actually trying to find the solution to their problem. We only get by because Google is so damn good at it's job. But errors are common to every programming language, every protocol, even hardware, so there *is* a niche for a universal place to discuss them, in a tidy directory organized by language and error code. I'm asking if StackOverflow is a good fit for that kind of project because it already has a great programmer Q&A community.

Comment: @WilliamHilton *"But ironically, while asking a question on SO is a last resort, searching through SO is the usually the first resort."* - that's not irony, that's exactly what's supposed to happen. It's still not clear to me what problem you think this new site would solve; if you're searching for an error message, how is it better to get links to Errors Overflow you should go and read than the same thing on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, because SO is totally disorganized, and searching for error messages isn't guaranteed to work. Auto-searching Stack Overflow isn't built into any software by default. Every language and OS has separate knowledge bases. Windows has a tool for trying to automatically find a solution to your problem when a program crashes, but that's about it. Which is a shame, because all the answers are probably there, in Stack Overflow, but since it's a Q&A format rather than a knowledge base or wiki or something, it doesn't have the structure to lead you to a solution efficiently.

Comment: @WilliamHilton so you want a completely different format? Then that's not a SE site so shouldn't be on Area 51. Also good luck wrangling all of those third party tools to use one data source! FWIW I have solved many problems by searching the error message leading me to SO questions.

Comment: I basically want to build a direct one-to-many mapping from error codes to solutions+discussions for solutions in progress. I'm asking if StackExchange is the right platform (I think the answer is no) and whether Stack Overflow community likes the idea (I think the answer is no?).

Comment: FWIW i solve problems every day by searching the error message and following Google to SO. It works because Google is good at its job, and despite SO. And I didn't think it had to be a completely different format. Just a more focused subsection dedicated to solving errors.

Answer (score -9):

The value of a definitive site focused on solving errors, and the ability to then integrate it with error messages in compilers, editors, and interpreters, seems obvious to me. I'm surprised that the gut reaction has been to rebut that there is "no need" for such a thing and in such a rude snarky way. I just wanted to make it easier for people to solve their errors darnit!

Comment: disagreement != rude and snarky

Comment: DamienPaul Agreed. The snarky refers to you, @RobertLongson, for quipping who is aiming to be an expert at errors?

Comment: The rude is referring to you @Makato, although you may not have meant to.

Comment: Robert's question sounds legitimate

Comment: If Robert's question sounds legitimate, then you have a very answerer-oriented view of SO. You're assuming that a stack exchange requires a group of experts who do nothing but answer questions to increase their karma points, rather than a place where peers will gladly share with others their solutions to common problems. Most of us don't think of Stack Overflow as a elite group of experts on the topic of programming. Most of us think of Stack Overflow as the definitive guide when shit hits the fan.

Comment: Do **not** ascribe assumptions to me

Comment: Whatever you wish to believe, I disagree that this idea is "awesome and useful" - of course that would make me a 'rude and snarky' member as i dared to disagree with your ideas.