# How should I review a clear question with no attempt?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I'm doing my first triage reviews, and I stumbled upon a question that was very clear. There was no problem in understanding the question at all. However, the poster had not made any attempt to solve it at all.

How should I think here?

The question was this: [getting a specific scope in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210020/getting-a-specific-scope-in-string)

(It may of course have changed when you read it.)

Comment: It is not a question, it is a task.  And no, "can somebody help me?" does not make it a question.

Comment: "It's not a question. It's a task." I like that.

Comment: It doesn't "look OK", only the OP can make it an acceptable question (doesn't "require editing"). I'd choose "Unsalvageable" with "Too broad" or "Unclear" as a close reason.

Comment: I picked requires editing, but maybe you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just because the question is *clear* doesn't mean that it's on-topic.

A heuristic I use [can be found here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337106/10793540), but critically it fails the points on "effort".  What they're looking for isn't help with a specific *issue*, they're looking to us to write their solution for them.

This is *definitely* too broad.  You can't narrow it down and no amount of editing can come from the OP to make their current question any better, so it's Unsalvageable.

How should you think?  Well...consider the close reasons when looking at a question.

- Is it clear?
- Is it overly broad?
- Is it a debugging question with no clear criteria of "success" or "failure"?
- Is it otherwise offensive?

If it's any of those things, then it should be cleaned up as quickly as possible.  Some of these things can be done with edits.  Most of these things are best left to downvote, flag/vote to close and move on.